# Windows Work Flow persistence database?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Few questions:
1. Is SQL server installation needed to run Windows Work Flow?
2. If yes, where does work flow stores (persists) data for a long running process
3. I see that some files are created in .\windows\Microsft.NET\Framework\v4.0\SQL\en\ (some sql scripts to create persistense points)
4. Do we need to run these scripts to manually create database?
5. Can we persist data on file system instead? so that we don't need to install SQL Server?

Thanks

Comment: The docs cover this.  They supply a Sql Server implementation, but you can make your own. Stored in the database. There are scripts you run to create the structure.  These can be found by reading the docs.  You can store it anywhere, you just have to write it.

Answer (score 1):

I see one supposed answer already, but "read the docs" answers really aren't good answers, especially in an area so poorly documented as WF, so in case anyone else stumbles across this thread:

(1) SQL Server doesn't have to be installed just to use workflows, but if you want persistence for long running workflows, (2) SQL Server is your easiest way to get it.

(3) and (4) You can let AppFabric do most of the heavy lifting in setting up the persistence database for you.

(5) you could persist on a file system instead of SQL Server but IMHO, from what I've seen in my short time with WF and persistence so far, you'd be crazy to try to implement your own persistence provider like that, especially when just starting out.  You can use SQL Server Express to get started.  Why reinvent the wheel?